# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la información del elemento seleccionado?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Estoy con una página que va mostrando dinámicamente los datos almacenados en una base de datos según se vayan seleccionando. Hasta ahora he conseguido mostrar un select y que al seleccionar algo aprezca otro cuyas opciones dependen de la opción elegida en el primer select. Lo que necesito es que se muestre la información de la opción escogida en el segundo select (que está almacenada en la base de datos). Sería algo similar a la imagen de abajo:

[image: solucion]

Lo que quiero es que después de clickar en la última opción (en la imagen el municipio), salga la información de este abajo (habitantes, gentilicio...). Todos esos datos están almacenados en la base de datos. El resultado que quiero obtener sería este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como digo, tengo ambos select ya hechos, me falta sólo mostrar la información del elemento seleccionado, pero no soy capaz de dar con la solución.

Dejo el código en pastebin porque aquí no me deja pegarlo:

[HTML](https://pastebin.com/U04WcHB1)

[PHP comarcas](https://pastebin.com/49ZnpsUh)

[PHP Municipios](https://pastebin.com/u2ruG2x4)

[Base de datos SQL](https://pastebin.com/8CbspbjX)

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si utilizas html5 no es necesario utlizar `XMLHttpRequest` puedes hacer lo mismo con [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

Comment: Es lo que utilizo en clase, así que ni idea de si debo de usar una cosa u otra jajaja

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Municipios de Cádiz</title>
  <script>
    function getInfo(url,callback){
     fetch(`${url}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok)
          return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data){
          callback(data); 
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
      });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      getInfo("data.php",function(comarcas){
        let content="";
        for(i in comarcas){
          content +=`<option value="${comarcas[i].id}">${comarcas[i].nombre}</option>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("comarca").innerHTML=content;
      });
    }

    function cleanDiv(selector){
      document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = "";
    }

    function municipios(comarcas){
      cleanDiv("pedania");
      cleanDiv("resultado");
      url = `data.php?comarca=${comarcas}`;
      getInfo(url,function(municipios){
          let  content= `Municipio: <select onchange="pedania(${comarcas},this.value)" id="municipio"><option> Seleccionar municipio </option>`;
            for (let i in municipios) {
             content += `<option value="${municipios[i].id}">${municipios[i].nombre}</option>`;
            }
            content += "</select>";
            document.getElementById("municipios").innerHTML = content;
      });
    }

    function pedania(comarcas,municipio){
      cleanDiv("resultado");
      url = `data.php?comarca=${comarcas}&municipio=${municipio}`;
      getInfo(url,function(pedania){
          let  content= `pedania: <select onchange="showInfo(${comarcas},${municipio},this.value)" id="pedania"><option> Seleccionar municipio </option>`;
            for (let i in pedania) {
             content += `<option value="${pedania[i].id}">${pedania[i].nombre}</option>`;
            }
            content += "</select>";
            document.getElementById("pedania").innerHTML = content;
      });
    }

    function showInfo(comarcas,municipio,pedania){
      url =`data.php?comarca=${comarcas}&municipio=${municipio}&pedania=${pedania}`;
      getInfo(url,function(data){
        let resultado =`<p>poblacion:${data[0].poblacion}</p>
                        <p>superficie:${data[0].superficie}</p>
                        <p>densidad poblacion:${data[0].densidad}</p>
                        <p>altitud: ${data[0].altitud}</p>
                        <p>gentilicio: ${data[0].gentilicio}</p>
                        <p>distancia: ${data[0].distancia}</p>
                        <p>pedanias: ${data[0].nombre}</p>`;
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=resultado;
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Provincia de Cádiz</h1>

  Comarca
  <select name="comarca" id="comarca" onchange="municipios(this.value)">
    <option value="-1">Seleccionar comarca</option>
  </select>
  <div id="municipios"></div>
  <div id="pedania"></div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

y una mejor forma de hacerlo es con un solo php para reutilizar codigo y hacer mas simple las urls:

```
<?php 

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cadiz");
$conexion->query("set names utf8");

if(isset($_GET['comarca']) && isset($_GET['municipio']) && isset($_GET['pedania'])){
    $comarca = filter_var($_GET['comarca'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $municipio = filter_var($_GET['municipio'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $pedania= filter_var($_GET['pedania'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    $sql ="select pedania.nombre, municipio.poblacion, municipio.superficie, municipio.densidad, municipio.altitud, municipio.distancia, municipio.gentilicio from municipio INNER join pedania on municipio.id = pedania.municipio_id where comarca_id =${comarca} and municipio.id =${municipio} and pedania.id =${pedania}";

}elseif (isset($_GET['comarca']) && isset($_GET['municipio'])){
    $comarca = filter_var($_GET['comarca'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $municipio = filter_var($_GET['municipio'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $sql = "select pedania.id, pedania.nombre, municipio.poblacion, municipio.superficie, municipio.densidad, municipio.altitud, municipio.distancia, municipio.gentilicio from municipio INNER join pedania on municipio.id = pedania.municipio_id where comarca_id =${comarca} and municipio.id =${municipio}";

}
elseif (isset($_GET['comarca'])) {
    $comarca = filter_var($_GET['comarca'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $sql = "select * from municipio where comarca_id = $comarca order by nombre";
}
else{
    $sql = "select * from comarca order by nombre";
}

$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    echo json_encode($resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "sorry no data"));
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. Lo acabo de comprobar y ya no sé si es problema de la base de datos o del código, pero hay veces que en los municipios sale undefined e incluso datos como la población no se actualizan a pesar de cambiar de municipio.

Comment: Vale, ya he visto lo que está pasando. El problema es que también me está pidiendo las pedanías y como hay algunos sitios que no tienen, sale undefined y no muestra la lista con los datos del municipio. ¿Sería posible hacerlo igual pero en que en vez de preguntar la pedanía la liste directamente al seleccionar el municipio? (Es decir, seleccionar una ciudad y que abajo junto a los datos salga: "Pedanías: ...")

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta trata sobre `ajax`, lo que debes hacer es guardar cada peticion en un metodo y esto lo invocas segun la secuencia que necesites, en este ejemplo, el `departamento -> provincia -> distrito` , puedes adecuarlo  `pais -> estado -> provincia`, etc

Suponiendo que la consulta ya esta correcta,

`{{url('api/departamento')}}` es la ruta a donde se hace la peticion, puedes notarlo como peticion en el navegador como:

`{dominio}/departamento.php` o tambien haces la peticion como `"/departamento.php"`

`{dominio}/provincia.php?iddep=2` o tambien haces la peticion como `"provincia.php?iddep=2"`

`{dominio}/distrito.php?iddep=2&pro=4` o tambien haces la peticion como `"/comarca.php?iddep=2&pro=4"`

pueden los nombres cambiar pero la idea es esa

```js
//Iniciamos con Departamento
      $.get("/departamento.php").then(function(ls){
         for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
             $("#dep").append('<option value="'+ls[i].dDepartamento+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
         }
         //$("#dep").val(us.departamento_id); //solo en caso de Actualizar
         provincia($("#dep").val());//pedimos cargar provincia
     });
      //metodo provincia, para la cual necesitamos Id departamento 
     function provincia(i) {
         $("#pro option").remove();
         $.get("/provincia.php?iddep="+i).then(function(ls){
             for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
                 $("#pro").append('<option value="'+ls[i].codProvincia+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
             }
             //$("#pro").val(us.provincia_id);//solo en caso de Actulizar
             distrito($("#dep").val(),$("#pro").val());//pedimos cargar distrito
         });
     }
      //metodo distrito
     function distrito(i,j) {
         $("#dis option").remove();
         $.get("/distrito.php?iddep="+i+"&pro="+j).then(function(ls){
             for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
                 $("#dis").append('<option value="'+ls[i].codDistrito+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
             }
             //$("#dis").val(us.distrito_id);//solo en caso de actulizar
         });
     }
      //detenctamos cambio de Departamento
     $('#dep').on('change', function(){
         provincia($("#dep").val());
     });
      //Detectamos cambio de Provincia
     $('#pro').on('change', function(){
         distrito($("#dep").val(),$("#pro").val());
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dep"></select>
<select id="pro"></select>
<select id="dis"></select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. El problema es que sigue sin salir la información como en la captura, salen todos los select de golpe y tampoco sale la información del sitio al final de la página como en la captura.

Comment: abre inspeccionar elemento en el navegador, ve a la pestaña `Network` o `Red`, ve si hay respuesta,